# CSS-Selector with no style-definition changes outcome

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

My problem is best described by these pictures:

[image: enter link description here]

[image]

Why does adding an empty style change the result?

*I'm using an example-css-layout (tympanus . net / codrops / 2012 / 06/12/css-only-responsive-layout-with-smooth-transitions/) and divided the stylesheet in several files.*

Comment: The reason appears to be because you have an extra character `^` after your comment (`*/ Colored sections */^`). If you delete that, you *most likely* won't need an empty style declaration. It's hard to tell without your code here.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.